# Needing a field filtered 3 ways ways for a line chart

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I'm not really sure how to implement a filter on a new measure I create. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/filter-function-dax) doesn't really fall into my use case. I can create a measure like this

```
ResolutionPercetage = DIVIDE(DISTINCTCOUNT(qry_Resolutions[WO#]),DISTINCTCOUNT(qryWorkOrders_AllTables[WO#]))
```

But I can't add the filter to this measure to make it specific to a region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my example data. You should use `FILTER` inside `CALCULATE`.

```
ResolutionPercetage = 
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT(qry_Resolutions[WO#]),
        FILTER(qry_Resolutions, [Region] = 5 )),
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT(qryWorkOrders_AllTables[WO#]),
        FILTER(qryWorkOrders_AllTables, [Region] = 5 )) )
```

qry_Resolutions:
[image]

qryWorkOrders_AllTables:
[image]

Result:
[image]